# Angular 4 | How can i control the display of a div in angular 4?

Tags: angular

How can i control the display of a div in angular 4? for example i have an input box, and when i input 2 it will only display 2 div and so on..

Example code:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
</div>
```

in the above it show all 5 boxes.. and i want to show only the boxes depending on the number i input in my inputbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="visNum">
  <div *ngIf="visNum === '1'" class="box">1</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum === '2'" class="box">2</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum === '3'" class="box">3</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum === '4'" class="box">4</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum === '5'" class="box">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not something like switch or ngif type.. i want to chieve is when i input the 2 in my input box. it will show the box1 and box2.. something like that.

Comment: you could try something like this if you wanted to show something based on being less than or equal to the vaue..  is that the goal???   <div class="container">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="visNum">
  <div *ngIf="visNum >= 1" class="box">1</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum >= 2" class="box">2</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum >= 3" class="box">3</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum >= 4" class="box">4</div>
  <div *ngIf="visNum >= 5" class="box">5</div>
</div>

Comment: you could also do this if you just wanted to show any number in the box:  <div class="container">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="visNum">
  <div class="box">{{visNum}}</div>
</div>

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the other answer, but you don't need `ngModel` from the `FormsModule`, you can use a template reference variable to refer to the `input` field's value.

```
<div>
  <input #myTextbox type="text" (keyup)="0">

  <div *ngIf="myTextbox.value >= 1">1</div>
  <div *ngIf="myTextbox.value >= 2">2</div>
  <div *ngIf="myTextbox.value >= 3">3</div>
  <div *ngIf="myTextbox.value >= 4">4</div>
  <div *ngIf="myTextbox.value >= 5">5</div>
</div>
```

See more [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) re: Template syntax.

**Updated:**

Taking another look at the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable) in the user input section, and you   *do* need an event to trigger change detection to have this update, here I've added a dummy `keyup` event.

Interestingly, this isn't explicitly mentioned on the template variables page, but a dummy `keyup` event is used in the live code sample they link to (if you check the source).

Here's the original issue discussing [this requirement](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/992).

Comment: Thanks man. this way better since i dont need to import formsmodule in my current app :) thanks man. all answer are correct thanks guys by the way :)

Comment: No problem - the other answers will also work, but this is the simplest way (in my opinion).

Comment: yes absolutely, but i wonder it didnt workout on my app :) should i import localref in my module also?

Comment: you are correct - I've updated the answer.  Forced me to re-read the Angular documentation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try This : I've used variable **makeSwitch**.

You can also use **ngIf** but in this case **ngSwitch** is more feasible.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="makeSwitch">
<div [ngSwitch]="makeSwitch">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="2">2</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="3">3</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="4">4</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="5">5</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>Nothing</div>
</div>
```

// OR

```
 <!-- Your Requirement -->
<div>
  <div *ngIf="makeSwitch >= 1">1</div>
  <div *ngIf="makeSwitch >= 2">2</div>
  <div *ngIf="makeSwitch >= 3">3</div>
  <div *ngIf="makeSwitch >= 4">4</div>
  <div *ngIf="makeSwitch >= 5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not something like switch or ngif type.. i want to chieve is when i input the 2 in my input box. it will show the box1 and box2.. something like that.

Comment: What if you input 4?

Comment: it will display box1, box2, box3, box4. somethime like that. input box here is somewhat my option in how much box i will display in my ui.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this, is what you want:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input [(ngModel)]="n" type="number">

      <div *ngIf="n > 0" class="container">
        <div *ngFor="let number of newArray(n); let i = index"  class="box">{{i}}</div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  n:number;
  constructor() {

  }

  newArray(numberOfInputs:number):number[]{
    return new Array(numberOfInputs);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5